# Cannot define EF 1 to 0..1 relationship properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am unable to defined 1:0..1 relationship in Entity Framework.

I have "`PerfData`" and "`AttachmentData`" entity. 
`Perf` is parent entity and it has zero or one `Attachment`.

In code `AttachmentData.CustomForeignKeyId` is FK to `PerfData.Id`, but in database FK should have different name `Attachment.PerfId` is FK to `PerfData.Id` (this is due to some base class and inheritance that I am not describing here).

```
public class AttachmentData {
   ... 
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public Guid CustomForeignKeyId{ get; set; } // this is FK to Perf.Id
   public PerfData Perf { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

and corresponding Configuration is

```
internal class AttachmentDataConfig : BaseConfig<AttachmentData>
    {
        public AttachmentDataConfig () : base("Attachment")
        {
            Property(x => x.CustomForeignKeyId)
                .HasColumnName("PerfId");

            HasRequired(o => o.Perf)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.CustomForeignKeyId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
    }
```

If I have only this, it works fine. Migration is generated properly. However, I also need to have navigation property on other side:

```
public class PerfData {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}    
    public AttachmentData> Attachment { get; set; } //navigation property
}
```

If I add this navigation property, then EF creates new migration with new column `Perf.Attachment_Id` that is unnecessary, as FK is already defined within `Attachment` table.

Comment: define inverse navigation property HasRequired(o => o.Perf)
                .WithMany(p=>p.Attachment)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.CustomForeignKeyId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Answer (score 0):

EF does not support 1:0..1 relationship with explicit FK column at the dependent side (it considers such relationship to be 1:0..N). For 1:0..1 it uses a so called [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) in which the PK of the dependent side is also a FK to the principal side.

With that being said, in your model the `CustomForeignKeyId` is redundant. The correct (from EF perspective) model would be like this:

```
public class PerfData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public AttachmentData Attachment { get; set; } //navigation property
}

public class AttachmentData {
   ... 
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public PerfData Perf { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

with the following configuration:

```
internal class AttachmentDataConfig : BaseConfig<AttachmentData>
{
    public AttachmentDataConfig() : base("Attachment")
    {
        HasRequired(e => e.Perf)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Attachment)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

**UPATE:** If you want to keep the existing FK field and use 1:0..N relationship, then change the `PerfData` class navigation property

```
public AttachmentData Attachment { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ICollection<AttachmentData> Attachments { get; set; }
```

and inside the configuration

```
.WithMany()
```

to

```
.WithMany(e => e.Attachments)
```

Comment: I need Attachment.CustomForeignKeyId. I need to be defined. First, because it is already defined in Base class (I omitted it for simplicity), but also because I have to set it.

Comment: Well, then the above of course does not work. But I would suggest you changing the post title because it's misleading - you can't have 0:0..1 this way (which is denoted by the word **Many** in `WithMany` in your configuration). I think I clearly stated in the beginning that what are you trying to achieve is not supported.

Comment: But what if it is ok for me to have 1: 0..many, how then to configure? I mean maybe I can get with such configuration (still I have 1 - 0..1, but I would configure as 0..many), maybe this works?